# Finding Image of a Linear Transformation, 3x1 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I have been researching on this question for three days now and just do not understand how to find the image, especially in this case.

**Question:** Find the $im(\alpha)$. Let $\alpha: \Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R^3$ be the linear transformation given by $$ \alpha:  \begin{bmatrix}
        a \\
        b \\
        c \\
        \end{bmatrix}\to \begin{bmatrix}
        a+b+c \\
        -a-c \\
        b \\
        \end{bmatrix}$$

I understand that the image is the column space of $\alpha$ but I do not understand exactly what it means to be that or how to find it. I have seen use of transpose but in this case I have a 3x1 matrix. Would this mean that the column space is 0 because you cannot of a linear combination or is it 1 because there is only 1 column?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think what you're meant to do is to find a basis for the image of $\alpha$.

Comment: The question from my text is exactly as written but with the addition of finding the kernel (which I was able to do). Is there a way to find the image ?

Comment: I suspect the point is that, denoting the coordinates of $\alpha$ as $(x,y,z)$, one has $x+y=z$ regardless of what $(a,b,c)$ is mapped.

Comment: You can rewrite the right side of your display as $$a(1,-1,0)+b(1,0,1)+c(1,-1,0)$$ so the image is the subspace spanned by $$\{\,(1,-1,0),(1,0,1),(1,-1,0)\,\}$$ Do you know how to find a basis for the subspace spanned by a given set of vectors?

Comment: I do not recall how to do that...I will try looking it up before checking back here.

Comment: Any progress, Aksel's?

Comment: Not yet. I shifted to another problem to make up for lost time. I will probably have time to look at it tonight.

Comment: If you want to be certain I see a comment intended for me, you have to write @Gerry in it.

Answer (score 1):

Finishing up Gerry Meyerson's comment, when we put the matrix whose rows are the spanning vectors in row-reduced echelon form, we get
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 0\\
1 &  0 & 1\\
1 & -1 & 0\end{bmatrix} \rightarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}.$$
The first two rows in the row-reduced echelon matrix give a basis for the image.  Vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ are expressed as column vectors, so a basis for the image of $\alpha$ is
$$\left\{ \begin{bmatrix} 1\\ 0\\ 1\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix} 0\\ 1\\ 1\end{bmatrix} \right\}.$$